# IndexError when creating squared list

Tags: python, append

Would you please consider the following code?

```
start_list = [5, 3, 1, 2, 4]
square_list = []
for i in start_list:
    square_list.append(start_list[i]**2)
print square_list
```

This code was meant to iterate over start_list and append each number squared to square list. So the output is meant to be:

```
[25, 9, 1, 4, 16]
```

Instead, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 4, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the values of start_list as positions of elements in start_list. The looping statement

```
for i in start_list
    square_list.append(start_list[i]**2)
print square_list
```

gives all values in start_list and then searches for elements with those values as indexes in start_list as can be seen when using the statement `start_list[i]`.
Instead, it should read:

```
for num in start_list:
    square_list.append(num**2)
print square_list
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the *values* in `start_list` as *indices*. The first such value is `5`, but you don't have a `start_list[5]`, giving you an `IndexError`. A Python `for` loop is a type of [Foreach loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreach_loop), you are given the contents of your list.

Don't use the values as indices. Just use the values *directly*; you assigned them to `i`, so square `i`:

```
square_list.append(i**2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a list comprehension also :

```
squarelist = [i**2 for i in start_list]
```

Or even this:

```
squarelist = list(map(lambda x: x**2, start_list))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple sol:

```
squarelist = [x**2 for x in start_list]
```

Or :

```
squarelist = map(lambda x : x**2 , start_list)
```

Or :

```
squarelist = []
for x in start_list : 
    squarelist.append(x**2)
```

Or

```
square_list = []
for i in range(len(start_list)):
     square_list.append(start_list[i]**2)
print square_list
```

Comment: Yeah the OP would have to wrap the second solution with `list( )`.

Comment: map function return a list